# How do I replace this non-standard T-strike plate in a metal jamb?

Tags: door-frame

I have several doors with metal jambs with a stamped indentation and pre-drilled holes for a T-shaped strike plate.  Some strike plates are missing and the remaining plates fit without extra space around them.

The plates measure 2 1/2" tall, and the hole centres are 1 15/16".  The tongue thingumy is 1 1/2" wide and begins to bend about 3/4" from the centre of the holes.

Unfortunately the only T-shaped strike plates I can find are 2 3/4" tall with hole centres at 2 1/8".  Google search isn't exactly friendly to numbers and fractions.

The best I can think of is if I try one of those 2 1/4"-tall rectangular strike plates and cut away anything that doesn't fit.  And if I really can't get the screw holes to line up then just glue them in.

That seems pretty messy, though.  Any better ideas?  Any magic search terms to help find the right part?

This is just indoor use to stop doors rattling in the wind.  No security concerns.

Comment: Instead of glue, you could simply drill new holes in the right places and screw them in. Unfortunately, though, this is a shopping question and those are off-topic.

Comment: The needed and original holes are too close together.  If the jamb were wood then I could just fill it before redrilling, but sadly no.  Both parts are metal and that seems to limit my reworking options.

Comment: The bad part about working with wood: Cut it too short and it's still too short. The good part about working with metal: Cut it too short and you can just weld more on! If you can't weld (I can't, but would love to learn), find someone local who is willing to bring his equipment by and fill in the holes. Once you've got solid metal there, you can drill & tap anywhere you want.

Comment: I can't very well take the jamb out to a safe place.  Is it realistic to try to weld in a clean way inside my bedroom, over the carpet?

Comment: I realised I could conceivably get one of these online laser cutting shops to do me a strike plate.  They may struggle to do the bend of the tongue with such small dimensions, but I think I could probably make a profile with an extra tag to make it bendable, and then use my dremel to nip that tag off when I get it.  This might actually be the way I go, but I'll see what they say about their metal selection and whether any of them would be suitable as a strike plate.

Comment: They make welding blankets designed specifically to cover other things to protect them from flying sparks & slag. Dunno how well they'd work indoors over carpet, but they've been known to protect auto interiors, so I'd think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re lucky enough to live somewhere that has a door specialist shop, take your existing strike there. Failing that, architectural scrap places might have bins you can spend hours sifting through.

If not, I’d just buy the nearest (over-)size, cut it to fit if needed, and drill/tap the screw holes to match the strike.